# The type or namespace name 'Lib' does not exist in the namespace 'IOUtility'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

So I am working on a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2010 for my IDE and working on two projects, the named IOUtility.UI and the other IOUtility.Lib. Now IOUtility.UI is a WPF project whereas IOUtility.Lib is a class Library project. So I add an IOUtility.Lib Project reference to IOUtility.UI, and proceeded to build my app. I reference some of the objects contained in my library project, in the UI project. Now when I go to build my whole solution(which contains just the two projects), I get the following error message

**The type or namespace name 'Lib' does not exist in the namespace 'IOUtility' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

When I view my reference properties for the IOUtility.Lib in IOUtility.UI, I see that Aliases is set to global, and copy local is set to true. Strong Name is false(I am not sure if there is a requirement that only assemblies with strong names can be used in WPF projects). I can verify that both projects are .NET 4.0, and the runtime versions are the same(v4.0.30319). What am I missing please ?

Comment: Are the classes in the `IOUtility.Lib` project actually in the `IOUtility.Lib` namespace? Namespaces and assembly names are different concepts - they just happen to often coincide.

Comment: Yes they are all in that namespace. what happens if when I reference the Lib object during development, in the IOUtility.UI project, it shows up(intellisense and all), however, when I go to run the IOUtility.UI project, I get the error message above. For some reason, it looses the reference it had to the library.

Comment: Is it possible that you are targeting the .NET Client Profile with your WPF project and the full .NET framework in your library? This would also cause the error you're facing. You can check this by right-clicking on a project and choosing "Properties". Then have a look at "Target framework".

Comment: Actually, that is the case. The WPF project targets client profile. According to the msdn page on both, "The .NET Framework 4 and earlier versions provided two deployment options: the full .NET Framework and the Client Profile, which was a subset of the .NET Framework that was optimized for client applications. The Client Profile enabled faster deployment and smaller app installation packages.".

Comment: Is it a problem building the libraries with the full and the the UI piece with the client profile of the framework?